# Why should ftime not be used?

Tags: c, linux, time

Quoting `man 3 ftime`:

> This function is obsolete.  Don't use it.  If the time in seconds  suffices,   time(2)  can  be  used;  gettimeofday(2)  gives  microseconds;
>          clock_gettime(2) gives nanoseconds but is not as widely available.

Why should it not be used? What are the perils?

I understand that `time(2)`, `gettimeofday(2)` and `clock_gettime(2)` can be used instead of `ftime(3)`, but `ftime(3)` gives out exactly milliseconds, and this I find convenient, since milliseconds is the exact precision I need.

Comment: First of all: it will be removed from libs because is obsolete...

Comment: Obsolete functions tend to be less portable, and may disappear one day when you least expect it. Better use a standardand supported function like `gettimeofday` and use simple arithmetic to get the time in milliseconds.

Comment: So why are they removing such a convenient function.

Comment: "ftime(3) gives out exactly milliseconds" - that's a bit misleading. It might give you exact milliseconds, it might not - the granularity is not guaranteed. The setting of the other fields in the struct was unspecified. The errors were unspecified... Use something more modern. Int division by 1000 isn't too expensive on usual platforms.

Comment: It's important to note that `ftime` used to be in the POSIX standards until 2008 - then POSIX removed it, so it's no longer any standard function, thus no longer portable.

Comment: "Why should ftime not be used?" --> because "function is obsolete."  There really is not more to be said.  If you want a rational about the pros/cons of "why it is obsolete.", that is another question.

Answer (score 1):

Such advice is intended to help you make your program portable and avoid various pitfalls. While the `ftime` function likely won't be *removed* from systems that have it, new systems your software gets ported to might not have it, and you may run into problems, e.g. if the system model of time zone evolves to something not conveniently expressible in the format of `ftime`'s structure.